# ActiveX and COM for interprocess communication

Tags: c++, com, activex, inter-process-communicat

I have a closed source program that generates ActiveX events, and I need to modify mine so that these events can be received. So we have two separate executables, and no GUI stuff is used. So far I got to this point, which only works if the event is generated and received by the same process:

```
[event_source(native)]
class CSource {
public:
    __event void MyEvent(int nValue);
};

[event_receiver(native)]
class CReceiver {
public:
    void MyHandler(int nValue) { ... }

    void hookEvent(CSource* pSource) {
        __hook(&CSource::MyEvent, pSource, &CReceiver::MyHandler);
    }

    void unhookEvent(CSource* pSource) {
        __unhook(&CSource::MyEvent, pSource, &CReceiver::MyHandler);
    }
};

int main() {
    CSource source;
    CReceiver receiver;

    receiver.hookEvent(&source);
    __raise source.MyEvent(123);
    receiver.unhookEvent(&source);
}
```

Now, the `event_source` is in the application I need to interface with. How can I connect the receiver and the source when they are in two separate processes?

Either an explanation or some references will be useful.

Answer (score 2):

1. You don't want attributed C++ since even though it is still supported, reality is that it has been deprecated since at the very least VS 2008
2. You need [`event_receiver(com`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3fw55ssh.aspx), not `native` type since ActiveX events are in question
3. The items above suggest that you don't use attributes and instead use [`IDispEventImpl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06wtz4t5.aspx) or `IDispEventSimpleImpl` class to implement receiver of ActiveX control events (the article gives code snippet and references sample project).